# Python - Jupyter - 'cannot import name _errors' for h5py

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, jupyter, h5py

I am trying to import a certain python file that uses h5py. When trying to run it, i get this error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c2fdc979da9d> in <module>()
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 import groupcat as catalog

/Users/username/Desktop/PythonFiles/groupcat.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 import h5py
      6 
      7 def gcPath(basePath,snapNum,chunkNum=0):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 try:
---> 13     from . import _errors
     14 except ImportError:
     15     import os.path as _op

ImportError: cannot import name _errors
```

I tried looking for a solution to this online, and I have read that there is a possibility that I am still inside the h5py install directory when trying to import the module.

If this is the case, how can I go about resolving this issue. If not the case, how can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try downloading the package again from H5PY https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py then manually from a command prompt, once you've extracted the files, go into the folder and be sure setup.py is in the current directory.  Type:

`python setup.py install`

You can be even more careful by specifying the directory of the package from where the installation files are located:

`python setup.py configure --hdf5=/path/to/hdf5`

Hopefully that clears up your error.

Comment: When going to input `python setup.py install` it says, [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: Are you sure the setup.py is in the current directory?